# three.js - Adjusting opacity of individual particles

Tags: three.js, point-clouds, particle-system

I am trying to vary the opacity of particles as a function of their distance from a plane.

[This issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/297) describes my problem, and the answer a year ago was essentially *"you can't"*. Opacity is apparently a parameter of a material, not an element, and hence individual particle opacity is not possible.

Has anything changed, is there any way I could achieve this? If individual particle colouring is possible, I imagine this isn't out of reach.

Cheers

Answer (score 32, accepted):

EDIT - This answer shows how to set per-point opacity using a custom `ShaderMaterial`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67892506/1461008 for an approach using `PointsMaterial`.

---

`ParticleSystem` has been renamed to `PointCloud` and then to `Points`.

Yes, you can create a Point Cloud and vary the alpha value of each particle's color dynamically.

In three.js, you can do this by setting the Point Cloud's material to be a `ShaderMaterial` having an attribute equal to the desired alpha value for each particle.

If `ShaderMaterials`, vertex shaders and fragment shaders are new to you, here is a *really simple* Fiddle that implements a Point Cloud with dynamic alphas: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lvrnpwc/.

EDIT: Updated fiddle

three.js r.148

Comment: Thanks! My current material is as follows:

   pMaterial = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
   size: 0.2,
   map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
    "images/particle.png"
   ),
   blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, 
   vertexColors: true,
   transparent: true,
   depthWrite: false, //needed?
  });

How can I keep the additive blending texture with this approach?

Comment: Alpha doesn't seem to work in the example anymore. I guess something must have changed in three.js causing this?

Comment: Okay, fixed it. I just had to set "transparent: true" at ShaderMaterial. http://jsfiddle.net/yfSwK/27/

Comment: do you know what the meaning of `gl.getProgramInfoLog() WARNING: Could not find vertex shader attribute 'position' to match BindAttributeLocation request.` in the console is? I'm also curious what this `position` is but I see from other sources it is something that THREE.js "provides".

Comment: btw if you are setting the attributes.alpha.value from another array, its a lot quicker to use `= otherArray.slice()` than a for loop

Comment: Apart from "gl_Fragcolor" what else can I set? Where can I find the reference for these built-in variables? A quick search for gl_Fragcolor shows nothing on this reference card: https://www.khronos.org/files/opengl44-quick-reference-card.pdf

Comment: This is really great. Do you have the shader code for updating the position of the particles as well? Or if you can have any great link.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but proposed solution didn't work for me. I used somewhat tricky shading to make points round and blurry at edges. So the corners of points were supposed to be transparent, but they appeared black: http://jsfiddle.net/5kz64ero/1/

Relevant part of my fragment shader:

```
// Distance from 0.0 to 0.5 from the center of the point
float d = distance(gl_PointCoord, vec2(0.5, 0.5));

// Applying sigmoid to smoothen the edge
float opacity = 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(16.0 * (d - 0.25)));

gl_FragColor = vec4(opacity * vColor, opacity);
```

I figured that traditionally this is solved by depth-sorting (with farthest points coming first), and I found some evidence that some older implementations of `ParticleSystem` in Three contained `sortParticles` attribute. But it's not there anymore. And in my case sorting would really involve redoing that every time camera position changes. Instead I set `depthWrite: false` and it seems to solve the issue.

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/5kz64ero/6/

Comment: The downside to this approach is that the points that should render behind render in front depending on the angle.