# Three.js ParticleSystem transparency issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, alphablending, fragment-shader

I'm using `Three.js` and I have a `ParticleSystem` where every particle may have a different transparency and color.

Code:

```
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: customUniforms,
    attributes: customAttributes,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
    transparent: true,
    alphaTest: 0.5
});


particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, shaderMaterial);
particles.dynamic = true;
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute float size;
attribute vec3 color;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {

    vColor = color;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

    //gl_PointSize = size;
    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float alpha;
varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 100);
    vec4 textureColor =  texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
    gl_FragColor = gl_FragColor *  textureColor;
    gl_FragColor.a = alpha;
}
```

Texture is a circle but when I set alpha, like this: `gl_FragColor.a = alpha`, my texture become a circle in a black square, alpha level is okay, but I don't need the square, only the circle if I don't set the alpha, square doesn't appear.
So how to set alpha correctly for provided texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: [three.js - Adjusting opacity of individual particles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337660/three-js-adjusting-opacity-of-individual-particles)

You can find jsfiddle somewhere in the page that uses `ShaderMaterial` for `ParticleSystem` with variable alpha: http://jsfiddle.net/yfSwK/27/

Also, at least change fragment shader a bit, `gl_FragColor` should be write-only variable, it's not usual to have it as a read-from variable:

```
vec4 col = vec4(vColor, 100);
vec4 tex = texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord );
gl_FragColor = vec4( (col*tex).rgb, alpha );
```

...or in one line:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4( (vec4(vColor, 100) *  texture2D( texture, gl_PointCoord )).rgb, alpha);
```

Comment: Thank you, the way like you do in example is that what I need. And I simplified my code,setting alpha only in vertexshader.<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader"> attribute float size;
   attribute vec3 color;
            attribute float alpha;
   varying vec4 vColor;

   void main() {

    vColor = vec4(color, alpha);

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / length( mvPosition.xyz ) );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

   }</script>