# How to get the same result as with using PointsMaterial but with using ShaderMaterial for the Points system

Tags: three.js, shader

I want to use `THREE.ShaderMaterial` instead of `THREE.PointMaterial`.
And have a problem with sizing or drawing of particles.

If I use `THREE.PointMaterial`, then sizes of particles depend on z coord of particle position (other words: depth of particle).
But, if I use `THREE.ShaderMaterial` then I lose the needed effect.

[Try it here](http://codepen.io/artzub/pen/dOrMGj)

[image: what I mean]

the left shpere is `THREE.ShaderMaterial`
the right shpere is `THREE.PointMaterial`

How you can see, have a big difference.

Maybe someone knows how to get the same result of rendering with using `THREE.ShaderMaterial`?

Code for mareials:

**`THREE.ShaderMaterial`**

```
const shaderPoint = THREE.ShaderLib.points
const uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shaderPoint.uniforms)
uniforms.map.value = /*set some texture*/
uniforms.size.value = 60
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    defines: {
        "USE_MAP": ""
    },
    transparent: true,
    // alphaTest: .4,
    depthWrite: false,
    // depthTest: false,
    // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    vertexShader: shaderPoint.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: shaderPoint.fragmentShader
}))
```

**`THREE.PointMaterial`**

```
let material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    size: 60,
    // color: "#f0f",
    map:  uniforms.map.value,
    depthWrite: false,
    transparent: true
})
```

Comment: Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337660/three-js-adjusting-opacity-of-individual-particles/12344288#12344288) and  [this comment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10385#issuecomment-267789138). That will give you ideas.

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for your comment. Really I found decision!!! If use `uniforms.scale.value = 350` and `USE_SIZEATTENUATION: ""` I have the same result :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need use `uniforms.scale.value = 350` and `USE_SIZEATTENUATION: ""` in order to say threejs to make correct shader vertex program.

**`THREE.ShaderMaterial`**

```
const shaderPoint = THREE.ShaderLib.points
const uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shaderPoint.uniforms)
uniforms.map.value = /*set some texture*/
uniforms.size.value = 60
/*+++*/
uniforms.scale.value = 350 // in my case value is 350
/*+++*/

material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: uniforms,
    defines: {
        USE_MAP: "",
        /*+++*/ 
        USE_SIZEATTENUATION: ""
        /*+++*/
    },
    transparent: true,
    // alphaTest: .4,
    depthWrite: false,
    // depthTest: false,
    // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    vertexShader: shaderPoint.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: shaderPoint.fragmentShader
}))
```

**UPD#1**
To be honest, if you don't need write yourself shader for `THREE.Points` then you should use `THREE.PointMaterial` because it's also shaders.

I looked over into [three.js source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/56ec5ce2e269d9fdf08ce6b385813c6ce0dc10ed/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2072) and found how to correctly calculate scale for uniforms parameters.
file: src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js
line: 2072
function: [refreshUniformsPoints](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/56ec5ce2e269d9fdf08ce6b385813c6ce0dc10ed/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L2072)