# Can you make individual points in a THREE.js Points object transparent/invisible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I have a Three.js Points object that contains data to display a bunch of points in the 3D space. I want to dynamically make some points invisible, but not sure how.

The material is a PointsMaterial. xyz data is stored in `pointsObj.geometry.attributes.position.array` and color data is stored in `pointsObj.geometry.attributes.color.array`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to alter things like alpha value or visibility of individual points (I can make *all* the points invisible, but this is different)

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Three.js doesn't support individual sizes or individual opacities for the default `PointsMaterial`. But it could be achieved if you make your custom `ShaderMaterial`. So the answer depends... are you comfortable writing shader code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12344288/1461008 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67892506/1461008

Answer (score 0):

Every point must have `color.array`, you can modify directly.

```
var colors = pointsObj.geometry.attributes.color.array;

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i += 4) {
  if (shouldPointBeInvisible(i)) { //<-- not implemented
    colors[i + 3] = 0; // Set alpha value to 0 to make the point invisible
  }
}

pointsObj.geometry.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
```

-- Here with a shader material maybe:

```
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: {
    visibility: { value: 1.0 }
  },
  vertexShader: `
    uniform float visibility;
    varying vec3 vColor;
    
    void main() {
      vColor = color;
      vColor.a *= visibility;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader: `
    varying vec3 vColor;
    
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
    }
  `
});

pointsObj.material = material;

...

if (shouldPointBeInvisible(i)) {
  pointsObj.material.uniforms.visibility.value = 0.0;
} else {
  pointsObj.material.uniforms.visibility.value = 1.0;
}
```

-- And another solution with PointsMaterial:

```
var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
size: 1,
transparent: true,
opacity: 1.0,
uniforms: {
visibility: { value: 1.0 }
},
vertexShader: `
uniform float visibility;
varying vec3 vColor;
oid main() {
  vColor = color;
  vColor.a *= visibility;
  gl_PointSize = size;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}

, fragmentShader: varying vec3 vColor;
`
});

pointsObj.material = material;

...

if (shouldPointBeInvisible(i)) {
pointsObj.material.uniforms.visibility.value = 0.0;
} else {
pointsObj.material.uniforms.visibility.value = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: I think the `color` attribute is a vec3 type without alpha. So when modifying `colors[i + 3]`, you’re simply changing the red channel of the subsequent vertex.

Comment: I ve edited my answer with a shader material, maybe it will works for u !

Comment: @ChristopheVanBeneden thank you! Is there a way to do this with a PointsMaterial instead of ShaderMaterial? I'm not sure how to use AlphaMap or if that's even useful here

Comment: @Peter I'd be wary of following any of these suggestions. `vColor` is a vec3, so `vColor.a` is invalid. The answer with `PointsMaterial` also wouldn't work because that material doesn't accept any of `uniforms`, `vertexShader`, or `fragmentShader` properties. Finally, `visibility` is a `uniform`, so it would apply to every point equally, which is exactly the problem you're trying to solve. I'm not sure where Christophe is getting these answers from.